# docker eclipse-mosquitto run only on localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, mosquitto

I want to use docker eclipse-mosquitto just for communication on a local machine. Which settings do I need for mosquitto.conf to make the mosquitto broker only visible on localhost but not from outside? Since a second mosquitto is running, port 1883 is blocked and I'm using port 1884.

This is what I have:

```
port 1884
bind_address 127.0.0.1
```

is visible from outside.

```
port 1884
bind_address localhost
```

gives error `Error: Address not available`.

Binding to docker-ip

```
port 1884
bind_address 172.17.0.1
```

gives error `Error: Address not available`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself:

Running docker with additional option `--network="host"` and than in mosquitto.conf:

```
port 1884
bind_address 127.0.0.1
```

does the job.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer is the wrong approach, you should only really be using `--network="host"` for things that need to open raw sockets or receive broadcast messages from the  local network.

The correct answer is to not use the `bind_address` option in the mosquitto.conf file and use the docker `-p` option to do the port mapping correctly ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)).

e.g.

```
docker run exec -rm -p 127.0.0.1:1884:1884/tcp mosquitto
```

Here the `-p 127.0.0.1:1884:1884` maps port 1884 in the container to port 1884 bound to the loopback ip (127.0.0.1) on the host.